# Delay in loading second function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to make this image fade into the one below it using a jQuery animation and then have the webpage load about 2 seconds after the fade. How do set a timer for the second function to load? Here is my code:

```
<html>                                                          
<head>                                                                  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.fade
{
z-index:1;}
.abs
{position:absolute;
    z-index: 10;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fadephoto">

    <div id="f4d" class="abs">
    <img  src="1.jpg" >

    </div>
<div class="fade">  <img src="4.jpg" /></div>
</div>

</body>  

<script>
{var fadeClicked = false;}
$("#f4d").click(function () {
$(this).fadeTo(2000, 0.01)
fadeClicked = true;
});

$('#fadephoto').click(function()
{
    if (fadeClicked)
    {
        window.location.href = ('http://www.ifdvidfji.com');
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use settimeout. Because you don't want to repeat code you can trigger the click event on your manual bypass.

http://jsfiddle.net/3nKDD/

```
$("#f4d").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(2000, 0.01)
    fadeClicked = true;
    setTimeout(function() { $('#fadephoto').trigger('click'); }, 2200);
});
```

Although I would restructure your javascript because right now clicking triggers both handlers and I think you only want it to trigger one of them.

http://jsfiddle.net/3nKDD/2/

Comment: that didnt seem to do anything

Comment: @MatthewVitebsky - try uncommenting the navigate line. I just wrote to console instead because it is annoying when your browser navigates away from your work area. You can see logs by pressing f12 or ctrl-shift-j to open your javascript debugging console. I also added a second fiddle that I think more accurately solves your problem.

Comment: thats almost perfect but it would be ideal if the fading started after a click instead of hovering. thank you for your help thusfar

Comment: hey thanks a lot for the help, i managed to edit your second code and use a different trigger for the link.
$('#f4d').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(2000, 0.01)
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#fadephoto').trigger('load');
}, 2600);
});
   


$('#fadephoto').load(function() {
    window.location.href = ('http://www.yahoo.com');
    console.log('navigate');
    
});